# How to update on client side at same time, when something changed from admin side in PHP, Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, server, request, push

Here I've two pages, the first one is admin panel (from where all CRUD operations can be done on quotes) and the second page is client side (where user can see today's quote).

Question:
When I'm updating quotes from admin panel (highlighted by red circle), the today's quote is successfully updating in database, and on admin side UI.
But I want it to update on client side as well at same time when the 'set' button in red circle is clicked without refreshing the page.

If i refresh the client side page then it's working fine, but how to do it without any reloading?

PS: I don't want to use `setInterval` function on client side which continuously send request to server for any update regarding quotes.

[image]

Comment: server sent events, websockets, etc.

Comment: Have you tried `AJAX`?

Comment: In the context of a server client relationship, you my intuitively think this works like having a conversation with a friend, where both parties can talk freely.  This in not correct, you could also think it works like a walkie-talkie where you push the button an say over etc.  That would also be wrong, even though both parties cant talk at the same time, there is still clear 2 way communication.  But this is not how it works.  It's more like ordering something from the store (by phone etc.) and then having it delivered to your house.

Comment: as nice as it would be to get additional packages you never ordered, it's just not going to happen.  If you want more stuff from the store you have to make a request for it, then the store sends out what you ordered.  So given this you can see there is no way the store can simply send you stuff.  Granted we can use things like Node.js and websockets to get around this, but you have to ask yourself are your users waiting around for this thing to change instantly?  Probably not, maybe they are I have no idea.  But it may be easier to add the next days quote the day before and just query by date

Answer (score -1):

I recommend [Socket.io](https://socket.io/). It connects your client to the server, and when you want to send something to the client(s) in real time, you can just do that easily.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
I tried to use Socket.io when didn't found any example using php.